# Wires not snapping to pins on component in Altium 19

Tags: altium, wiring

I updated my PCB document based on my schematics and noticed a few nets were missing between components. For example, my current limiting resistor doesn't have a visible net to my LED.

I went back to my schematic and they look visually connected. When I clicked and dragged my LED with my mouse away from its position, I noticed the wires were snapped to the pins (they weren't moving with the LED,) which seems to me like they're not '*connected.*'

However, no matter why I do they are not snapping. I have other components where one pin has successfully connected to a wire, but the second pin has not, and the net isn't showing.

Is there something I'm not doing properly? Is it to do with when I created the schematic symbol?

I appreciate any help, first time making a PCB in Altium and couldn't find any clear answer online.

Comment: It might be useful if you posted a screenshot of the affected portion of the schematic. One of the reasons this might happen is that the grid is not aligned with the pins on the component(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out, the problem did lie within the Schematic Symbol designing. I didn't realise when you attach pins, they have a 'direction'.

I was placing the snap point of the pin towards the inside of the component rather than the outside during symbol designing, so this meant unless I was placing wire directly to the far end of my pin in the actual schematic, nothing was actually connecting.

Flipping these pins and updating my schematic from libraries fixed the problem completely! Hope this helps someone, someday.

I've attached an image that shows when the pin is now the correct direction, the tiny little white dot on the end symbolises the snap point.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, in the schematic editor, click Project -> Compile document [your schematic document.SchDoc]

Then in the bottom right hand corner click System -> Messages.

This window should tell you about any errors in the schematic that could cause problems when moving across to the PCB.

Make sure to snap to the same size grid when creating your schematic symbols as you use in the schematic editor. This prevents OffGrid errors, which can lead to bad connections in the schematic.